# Can these two queries be considered same or not?

Tags: sql-server, join, select, syntax

Let's say I've two tables Customers$, Orders$. I want to know as both of these (given below) give same results. So, Can I use any one of it or second method in place of inner join.

```
select Orders$.OrderDate,
       Customers$.ContactName
from Orders$
     inner join Customers$ on Orders$.CustomerID = Customers$.CustomerID;

select Orders$.OrderDate,
       Customers$.ContactName
from Orders$,Customers$
where Orders$.CustomerID = Customers$.CustomerID;
```

But when I'm solving a question from -
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/average-population-of-each-continent/problem

So both should work fine, but second one is not working as u said in your comment that these both are same

```
select country.continent , round(avg(city.population -.5 , 0))  from country, city where country.code=city.countrycode group by country.continent;

select country.continent, round(avg(city.population - .5),0) from country inner join city on country.code=city.countrycode group by country.continent
```

Comment: Yes, but why would you intentionally choose to use syntax from the 1980's? It's 2019. The ANSI92 JOIN syntax has been around for 27 years and there's no good reason to not use it.

Comment: That doesn't answer why you would use 30 year old coding practices, instead of the newer standards that superseded them only 3 years later. ;)

Comment: Those second 2 statements aren't equivilent. `round(avg(city.population -.5 , 0))` <> `round(avg(city.population),0)`. Also, I strongly suggest using whitespace and indentation when writing SQL; single line code is very hard to read (have a look at what I did with your first statements as an example).

Comment: yeah thanks, I did mistake and couldn't find . Now got it

Comment: Just one reason why good formatting makes things easier. Errors are much easier to sot. Especially if an error generating a syntax error like "Error on Line 1". If you're SQL is 1 line, it could be anywhere, but "error on line 275" gives you a much better chance.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two queries are equivalent. While both are technically correct, the modern syntax encourages using explicit joins, and you should stick with the first variant.